# Error con SqlSysClrTypes.msi al intentar instalar mi aplicacion en C# y SqlServer

Tags: c#, sql-server

Tengo una aplicacion desarrollada en C# con SqlServer 2014 y tengo la base de datos incorporada en el proyecto.
Cuendo instalo el programa en mi pc no tengo inconvenientes y el programa funciona correctamente.
El error aparece al intentar instalar la aplicacion en el cliente con windows 7; comienza la descarga de archivos necesarios hasta que en un momento lanza el error

> La instalación ha detectado que el archivo c://...ruta..//SqlsysClrTypes.msi ha cambiado desde que se publicó inicialmente.

y luego de este mensaje se cancela la instalación.

Encontré que quizá el error se deba a que la versión de SqlServer.Types.dll es distinta a la instalada en el SO, en el programa la versión que tengo es la 12.0.0.0 pero no encuentro la que está en el SO.

La ruta para verificar la version del SqlSysClrTypes en el registro de windows es:

> HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{718FFB65-F6E4-4D62-861F-ED10ED32C936}

Pensé en actualizar de alguna manera la versión que tengo en mi aplicación pero no sé de qué manera hacerlo.

Comment: Descubrí que el error apareció debido a que en un principio accedía a la base de datos que creé en mi instancia de Sql Server instalada en mi laptop pero luego intenté cambiar a una base de datos incorporada al proyecto, hice todas las modificaciones necesarias y el programa funciona correctamente pero al intentar instalarlo en el cliente me lanza este error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error se debía a que en los prerequisitos del instalador tenía seleccionados (además del framework necesario) los archivos de `SqlsysClrTypes`. Así que deseleccioné estos archivos y pude instalar el programa en el cliente sin problemas.